# How to detect MIME type of plain text files: CSS, Javascript, ini, sql?

Tags: php, file, mime-types

Detecting the MIME type of a file with PHP is trivial - just use PEAR's [MIME_Type](http://pear.php.net/package/MIME_Type) package, PHP's [fileinfo](http://php.net/fileinfo) or call `file -i` on a Unix machine.
This works really well for binary files and all others that have some kind of "magic bytes" through which they can be detected easily.

What I'm failing at is detecting the correct MIME type of plain text files:

- CSS
- Diff
- INI (configuration)
- Javascript
- rST
- SQL

All of them are identified as "text/plain", which is correct, but too unspecific for me. I need the real type, even if it costs some time to analyze the file content.

So my question: Which solutions exist to detect the MIME type of such plain text files? Any Libraries? Code snippets?

---

Note that I neither have a filename nor a file extension, but I have the file content.

---

If I used ruby, I could integrate [github's linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist). Ohloh's [ohcount](https://github.com/blackducksw/ohcount/) is written in C, but has a command line tool to detect the type: `ohcount -d $file`

### What I've tried

#### ohcount

Detects xml and php files correctly, all other not.

#### Apache tika

Detects xml and html, all other tests files were only seen as `text/plain`.

Comment: It's just guessing... What about invalid CSS files (syntax errors)? Why do you need that?

Comment: `github-linguist` has a CLI now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I didn't find a proper library, I wrote my own *magic* file that detects all of my test files properly.

My application first tries my custom magic file for detection and falls back to the normal/system magic file if no type is detected.

The code it on github, see https://github.com/cweiske/MIME_Type_PlainDetect .
The magic file is at [data/programming.magic](https://github.com/cweiske/MIME_Type_PlainDetect/blob/master/data/programming.magic) and can be used with `file -f programming.magic /path/to/source`

Comment: can you post the code that answered your question? It would help a lot of those who stumble upon this thread.

Comment: The *nix command should be file -m programming.magic /path/to/source.

PHP would look like such:

    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, '/usr/local/apache/conf/programming.magic');
    $mime = $finfo->file($tmpfname);

Comment: There is a README now -> https://github.com/cweiske/MIME_Type_PlainDetect

Answer (score 2):

I think *Magical detection* from Apache Tika could help you:

http://tika.apache.org/

Comment: How does that help me? It's a method that uses the file extension to return a mime type. I specifically stated that I do not know the filename.

Comment: I have the file content. That can be inspected, as most MIME detection tools do it.

Comment: You could then recognize MIMEs with some hardcoded keywords and you could just program a kinda compilator/parsor.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Since it's a lot of work I asked this question: "Which solutions exist ...".

Comment: @Pier-alexandre Bouchard - yours sounds like it might be an excellent solution.  thank you for contributing :)  IMHO...

Answer (score 2):

How to :

- **.ini** To check ini files, you'll use [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function. It return false if the ini file is wrong.
- **.css** First check if you find something like that `body {`,  `html {` or  `body, html {`. You can also try keywords from CSS like `font-family`, `background`, `border`, etc.
- **.sql** You will likely find something like `INSERT INTO`, `UPDATE (.*) SET`, `CREATE TABLE`, etc, again look for keywords.
- **.js** For Javascript, you will have to find parse everything again for keywords...

For others, I don't know them.

Comment: What if a file is a [polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29) according to the defined rules? I could potentially upload a file that looks like css but actually contains PHP (like this: `/* <?php evil code here ?> */`) which is a security risk.

Comment: It's just used for syntax highlighting, so there is no harm being done.

Comment: What I suggest @cweiske is to go on the website of Notepad++, take the source and check for the code that highlight everything (it's based on regex). You could easily insert it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I found this library: http://pear.php.net/package/MIME_Type/

According to its description it "Provides functionality for dealing with MIME types." and gives the following features:

- Parse MIME type.
- Supports full RFC2045 specification.
- Many utility functions for working with and determining info about types.
- Most functions can be called statically.
- Autodetect a file's mime-type, either with fileinfo extension, mime_magic extension, the 'file' command or an in-built mapping list